# Remove One Object from Array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to remove one object in array. for example:

```
[Object {
    Name = "David", Position = "Developer"
}, Object {
    Name = "Michael", Position = "Designer"
}]
```

I want to get like that.

```
[Object {
    Name = "David", Position = "Developer"
}]
```

How can I solve it.

Comment: Try [`arr.splice(1,1);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: What is the criteria for removing the item? Can you add some more context?